# Disable nginx's index.html

Tags: nginx

I see an error like this:

```
"/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory
```

However my website has no index.html, because...2018.

Is there a way to disable nginx's error to not care about that file?

Comment: You mean your website is working properly and you just need to avoid this error? This is curious. Would you mind to describe your setup? Nginx has **index** directive, by default it's 'index.html', so I'm wondering how your website works

Comment: Correct. I use [nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/) which doesn't redirect `/index.html` to the entrypoint. So the main entrypoint of the website is only `/` path and not `/` + `/index.html`.